# Gradient Brush in Native C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, native

In c#, you can use drawing2d.lineargradientbrush, but in c++ right now I only found the CreateSolidBrush function. Is there a function in the native gdi dll to create a gradient brush? I couldn't find anything like this at msdn.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw a vertical gradient:

```
void VerticalGradient(HDC hDC, const RECT& GradientFill, 
                      COLORREF rgbTop, COLORREF rgbBottom)
{
    GRADIENT_RECT gradientRect = { 0, 1 };
    TRIVERTEX triVertext[ 2 ] = {
        GradientFill.left - 1,
        GradientFill.top - 1,
        GetRValue(rgbTop) << 8,
        GetGValue(rgbTop) << 8,
        GetBValue(rgbTop) << 8,
        0x0000,         
        GradientFill.right,
        GradientFill.bottom,
        GetRValue(rgbBottom) << 8,
        GetGValue(rgbBottom) << 8,
        GetBValue(rgbBottom) << 8,
        0x0000
    };
    GradientFill(hDC, triVertext, 2, &gradientRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a combination of the Win32 API [`GradientFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gradientfill), [`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap), and [`CreatePatternBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createpatternbrush).

Answer (score 2):

C# uses GDI+ for Drawing2d. You can use GDI+ in C++ also - [MSDN Creating a Linear Gradient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533914%28VS.85%29.aspx)