# How to draw fading square or a fading circle in a square c++ win32

Tags: c++

I do want to draw colored fading (to black) circle in a small square. What i need to control is the fading intensity updating it quite fast. I do know how to fill and control full square color, and my current algorithm is quite simple:

```
RECT r;
GetClientRect(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 1), &r); //get CLIENT rect of control relative to screen
brush_real = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(Roriginal, Goriginal, Boriginal));
dc = GetDC(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 1));
FillRect(dc, &r, brush_real);
DeleteObject(brush_real);
ReleaseDC(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 1), dc);
```

Win32 and basic microsoft libraries preffered, but anything else fits... 
Can someone give me any examples, or at least which functionality i should research ? as specificly as possible.

Comment: Do you mean draw a "gradient" which blends from one color to another? If so this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1418399/3651800

Answer (score 0):

Given your use of the word 'fast' in your question, I'm assuming you'd like to the fade to occur in the time-domain, rather than a spatial one.

With that said, the way I'd go about it is to simply use a timer and a static variable. Every time the timer fires, I'd change the variable and request a repaint. During the repaint, I'd examine the variable and use it to control the colour of the circle I drew.

Here's a quick sample that draws a grey square that encloses a circle. Over 100 frames, the circle changes from black (0,0,0) to red (255,0,0). Do note that the circle is draw with both the HBRUSH and the HPEN that are currently selected into the HDC. I haven't bothered with the HPEN, so you'll notice that the circle has a black outline, since the default pen is a black one.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;


// hwnd = dest wnd
// percentage - 100% = black, 0% = red
void onPaint(HWND hwnd, int percentage)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    RECT mRect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &mRect);
    SetRect(&mRect, 10, 10, 100+10, 100+10);
    HBRUSH bkBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(100, 100, 100) );
    FillRect(hdc, &mRect, bkBrush);

    int col = ( (100-percentage) * 255) / 100.0;
    HBRUSH circleBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(col,0,0) ), oldBrush;
    oldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, circleBrush);
    Ellipse(hdc, mRect.left,mRect.top, mRect.right,mRect.bottom);
    SelectObject(hdc, oldBrush);

    DeleteObject(bkBrush);
    DeleteObject(circleBrush);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int percentage = 100, framesPerSecond = 60;
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        SetTimer(hwndDlg, 0x666, 1000/framesPerSecond, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_TIMER:
        {
            if (percentage)
                percentage--;
            else
                KillTimer(hwndDlg, 0x666);

            InvalidateRect(hwndDlg, NULL, false);
         //   printf("wm_timer\n");
        }
        return false;

    case WM_PAINT:
        onPaint(hwndDlg, percentage);
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

Comment: Hello, i wanted to blur the circle to sides not color of the circle .
I mean - draw a round circle in middle and blur it to sides.
the blur - i mean transparent to background more and more.

Comment: And fast repainting of ellipse after fillrect(fill background with black or whatever) causes ellipse repaint to flicker, i am thinking about filling background only once and let the circle paint over and over. but not quite sure how to do that properly